# JavaScript regexp?

Tags: javascript

This is the regexp:

```
$("#newpassword").keyup(function(e) { 
  var htm = "";
  var pass = this.value;
  var length = this.value.length;

  if (pass) {
    var score = 0;
    if(length >= 8 && length <= 16) { //PASSWORD MIN/MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS

      var upper = /[A-Z]/;
      var lower = /[a-z]/;

      var number = /^[0-9]+$/; //PATTERN FOR NUMBERS
      var schar = /[!@#$%^&*?_~+-=<>]/;

      //LOOPS THROUGH PASSWORD TO CHECK FOR AT LEAST ONE OF EACH PATTERN
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (pass.substr(i, 1).match(upper)) {
          var uletters = true;
          score ++;     
          //AT LEAST ONE LETTER EXISTS
        }
        if(pass.substr(i,1).match(lower)) {
          var lletters = true;
          score++; 
          //AT LEAST ONE LETTER EXISTS
        }
        if(pass.substr(i,1).match(schar)) {
          var schar = true;
          score++;
        }
        if(pass.substr(i, 1).match(number)) {
          var numbers = true; 
          var schar = false;
          //AT LEAST ONE NUMBER EXISTS
          score++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The any two condition is true means password is ok, but the above code  `if(numbers == true && schar == true)` user type only number display password ok.

Please help me what is the problem in my code.

Comment: It helps get you better answers sooner if you take the time to format the question so it's easy to read. Posting it such that the code is indented way over for no good reason doesn't do that. Also, your code is incomplete (syntax error, at least three missing `}`s). I was going to clean it up for you, but I don't want to introduce misleading indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over each character of your password, just do the following:

```
score += upper.test(password)?1:0;
score += lower.test(password)?1:0;
score += number.test(password)?1:0;
score += schar.test(password)?1:0;
```

(`test` returns true or false) and check the score afterwards.

In general it's recommendable not to be too restrictive about the users password. It seriously harms the user experience if they are told to how their password should look like. You can make it a recommendation though. (E.g. display a bar: weak (red) - strong (green) password. This is much more motivating than harassing the user with any error messages.) Let them pass on score 2 and higher.

Comment: `score += upper.test(password)?1:0;` can be shortened to `score += +upper.test(password);` and even the unary + is unnecessary. So your answer could be coded as `score += upper.test(password) + 
lower.test(password) + number.test(password) + schar.test(password);`

Comment: @HBP Sure you could do an arbitrary amount of code-golfing. However, you write code only once but read at least 10 times. I always prefer readability over compactness. Each LOC which makes you think more than necessary is probably too obfuscated (like your last example). Also I would not use type coercion to such a heavy extend. Always think of your poor co-workers who have to reread your code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use RegExp.test() or RegExp.exec() to "find" a regex match within your string, rather than iterating the characters yourself.

```
function validatePwd (pwd) {
    if (pwd.length < 8)
        return false;
    if (pwd.length > 16)
        return false;

    var upperPatt =  /[A-Z]/;
    var lowerPatt =  /[a-z]/;
    var numberPatt = /[0-9]/;   // FIXED -- this is a better pattern for numbers.
    var scharPatt =  /[!@#$%^&*?_~+-=<>]/;

    score = 0;
    if (upperPatt.test( pwd))
        score++;
    if (lowerPatt.test( pwd))
        score++;
    if (numberPatt.test( pwd))
        score++;
    if (specialPatt.test( pwd))
        score++;

    // don't make it too hard for the poor user, please..  
    //    -- they have to type all this horrible rubbish.
    if (score < 3) {    
        return false;
    }

    // OK.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hai,the above  code working fine in number and character.but user type number display score value is 2.what is the problem in numberpatt and specialpatt.anybody plz help me.i want to  without allowed whitespace.

Comment: I think the number pattern (you gave originally) was broken. Please +1 the answer, anyway.